# Is it possible to have a page name and, a folder name that consists of dynamic pages, to be the same?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-router, dynamic-routing, dynamic-pages

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCPdb.png)

In the above image, I have a page named "Movies" and I also have a folder named movies

I want to navigate in a way that if the address bar has the url of '/movies' it should take me to the "movies.js" page and only if the address is something like '/movies/123', it should take me to the page with that specific ID.

But it doesn't seem to work that way. When I navigate to '/movies' it takes me to the movies.js page but after i navigate to '/movies/123' and then go back, it takes me to a '/movies' but the movies.js page is not rendered. I instead see a blank screen. Please tell me if it's possible to have a page name and a folder name to be same in Next JS.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `movies/index.js` to your `movies` folder.

More info on the [next documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/introduction#linking-between-pages)

Comment: Already did. Didn't work  :(

Comment: You may have a typo or something because it must work. Can you share your repo?